# How do STO-based computer programs implement the STO integral formulae?

Tags: computational-chemistry

In most cases, STO integrals are evaluated assuming that the orbitals are directed towards each other, using spherical harmonics; however, in GTO-based software Cartesian GTOs are used, with the orbitals being aligned along the x, y or z axis.

Is there any way to evaluate STO integrals using Cartesian STOs, or convert between Cartesian and spherical STOs? For example, if I had a pz-type STO at (0,0,0) and another one at (1,1,1), is there any way to decompose the resultant expression in terms of spherical STO integrals?

Comment: I would wager that the relevant recursion formulae are listed in L. Zülicke: Quantenchemie, unfortunately, it is hard to come by.

Comment: Have you considered to commit to the Materials Modeling Stack Exchange: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGY4NjYyM2ZlY2NkNDI0MWRmYjhjMGI1N2RmM2U3ZDk1N2VjOWQ1MGU1MmVhNDZkZjI5MzNiNzY1MmE2ZjRhOYrAzULyFn6juGAbZ7wko5LvlWXZ0iQfr620nQ70gVNl0 ? There's a higher concentration of computational researchers, including basis set expert Kirk Peterson. Several example questions were about basis sets. We will soon be in the private beta phase, where only a select group of users can participate. These users help to determine the style of questions for the future.

Comment: Are you able to be specific about which particular computer program for which you're interested in the STO implementation? I know at least 2 programs that use Slaters and the implementation is very different in each of them.